# How to refresh current ionic view after deleting item

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi i am new to ionic framework. I am displaying data in  list view and data source is sqlite. I added swipe to delete functionality. Item deleted successfully but it is showing in list until i refresh view manually. 
Please help me how to refresh current ionic view.

Comment: have a call back to your delete event listener, if successful: refresh or reload.

Comment: Thanks . i tried but it is not working. please give references to reload current page

Comment: Probably a reload is not necessary. Just remove the same item from the scope variable from the `ng-repeat` of your ionic list and the list will be refreshed as well.

Comment: You'll need to post some code if you want to help us further, but as JanP described, removing it from the scope variable should solve your issue.